# I can't see a fireball in mc 1.13

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I can only see a fireball summoned for a split second, and then it disappears...

It will show itself every five seconds or so, but I pretty much can't see it.

It still exists within the world, as when i kill it, it's still there and says "Fireball killed"

I can't see it when I use the summon command below:

```
/summon minecraft:fireball ~ ~2 ~ {Explosionpower:0,direction:[1.0,0.0,0.0]}
```

but I can see it when ghasts shoot at me.

How do I fix this?

Comment: `ExplosionPower`, not `Explosionpower`

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the bug [MC-145140](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-145140). So far no workaround is known. The best you can do is voting for that report.

Comment: Yeah for some reason it works if I give it velocity but if it is stationary it just glitches in and out depending on what angle I look at it at. I was wondering if that was a bug or the tags changed and my 1.13 stuff was wrong. Guess it's a bug.